# Question of derivatives

Tags: calculus

If $\psi\in C^2(\bar\Omega)$, $\Omega=(0,1)$ and let $x^\ast$ be such that $\psi(x^\ast)=\min_\bar\Omega\psi(x)$. Assume $\psi(0)\geq0$ and $\psi(1)\geq0$. Suppose $\psi(x^\ast)<0$. Why is $\psi'(x^\ast)=0$ and $\psi''(x^\ast)\geq0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your assumptions the point $x^*$ where $\psi$ assumes its global minimum on $\bar\Omega$ is in the interior of $\bar\Omega$. It follows that there is an $\epsilon>0$ with $[x^*-\epsilon, \ x^*+\epsilon]\subset\Omega$.

According to Taylor's theorem we may write
$$\psi(x)-\psi(x^*)=\psi'(x^*)(x-x^*)+r(x)(x-x^*)=\bigl(\psi'(x^*)+r(x)\bigr)(x-x^*)\tag{1}$$
for some function $x\mapsto r(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to x^*}r(x)=0$.

Assume $$\psi'(x^*)=:c\ne0\ .\tag{2}$$ Since for $x$ sufficiently near $x^*$ we have $|r(x)|<c$ it follows from $(1)$ that
$${\rm sgn}\bigl(\psi(x)-\psi(x^*)\bigr)={\rm sgn}(c)\cdot {\rm sgn}(x-x^*)$$
for $x$ on either side sufficiently near $x^*$. Therefore $\psi(x)-\psi(x^*)$ assumes as well positive as negative values in the immediate neighborhood of $x^*$. In this case $\psi$ can not even have a local minimum at $x^*$, let alone a global minimum. We conclude that the assumption $(2)$ cannot be upheld.

So we know now that $\psi'(x^*)=0$. Using Taylor's theorem again we may write
$$\psi(x)-\psi(x^*)={\psi''(x^*)\over2}(x-x^*)^2+r(x)(x-x^*)^2=\left({\psi'(x^*)\over2}+r(x)\right)(x-x^*)^2\tag{3}$$
for some other function $x\mapsto r(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to x^*}r(x)=0$. Assume $$\psi''(x^*)=:-p<0\ \tag{4}$$ Since for $x$ sufficiently near $x^*$ we have $|r(x)|<p$ it follows from $(3)$ that  for $x$ sufficiently near $x^*$, but $\ne x^*$, we would have $\psi(x)-\psi(x^*)<0$, contrary to our assumption that $\psi$ assumes its minimum at $x^*$. We conclude that the assumption $(4)$ cannot be upheld.

Comment: I am a bit lost with your reasoning. I dont get sgn$(\psi(x)-\psi(x^\ast))=$sgn$(c)$.sgn$(x-x^\ast)$. What is it used for? Shoud you not consider the sign of $r(x)$ in $sgn(\psi(x)-\psi(x\ast))$=sgn$(c)$.sgn$(x-x\ast)$? Also is $x>x^\ast$? I also dont see how $\psi$ would not even have a local minimum at x∗, let alone a global minimum.

Comment: @Vaolter: See my edit. Using the ${\rm sgn}$-function allows to cover all possible cases, like $x<x^*$, $x>x^*$, $\psi'(x^*)>0$, $\psi'(x^*)<0$, in one big swap.

Comment: I think you need to provide cases before you say " Therefore $\psi(x)−\psi(x^\ast)$ assumes as well positive as negative values in the immediate neighborhood of $x^\ast$". Could this proof have been easy with $r$ spelt out. I am confused. Can you consider a proof without this sgn?

Comment: @Vaolter: The essential point is that ${\rm sgn}$ is multiplicative: ${\rm sgn}(x\cdot y)={\rm sgn}(x)\cdot{\rm sgn}(y)$. That's my last word in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

If $\bar\Omega$ is intended to mean the closure of an open set $\Omega$, then the desired conclusion doesn't follow if $x^*\in\bar\Omega-\Omega$. For example, let $\Omega$ be the open interval $(0,1)$, so $\bar\Omega$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$, and define $\psi$ by $\psi(x)=-x^2$.  Then $x^*=1$ and both $\psi'$ and $\psi''$ are, depending on your conventions about endpoints, negative or undefined at $x^*$.

Comment: If, on the other hand, $\bar\Omega$ doesn't mean what I supposed, then the OP should tell us what it's intended to mean.

Comment: I have added more information.

Comment: It seems $0$ and $1$ are known elements of $\overline{\Omega}$, whatever it is...

Comment: @GEdgar, $\Omega$ is now defined.